# Light absorption through solution containing hypochlorous acid

Tags: visible-light

I'm a computer scientist and I would like to build a chlorine detector that doesn't involve reagents. I suspect that this isn't possible as someone would probably have already built such a thing if it were.

Is there a specific wavelength of light that is absorbed by pool chlorine or one of its related compounds? I envisioned having an LED on one end of the pool and detector on the other end.  By measuring how much light made it from the emitter to the detector (in stagnant water), I would be able to determine the state of the chlorine level of the pool and possibly trigger a feeder system when necessary.

Comment: Interesting question, though it might fit better on Engineering SE. Let's see if it gets answered =)